# I want to display same items from arraylist in recyclerview

Tags: java, android

ArrayList arrayList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
String iconsName[] = {"priya", "latha", "geeta", "sneha", "varsha", "vanitha", "rani", "raji", "gam"};

```
Integer icons[]={101,102,101,102,101,102,101,102};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
        itemModel itemModel = new itemModel();
        itemModel.setNumber(icons[i]);
        itemModel.setName(iconsName[i]);

        
        arrayList.add(itemModel);



    }
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

This is my code So i want only 101 items should be displayed

Comment: 101 items displayed where? Is there any filter or you just want to show items with icon as 101. I want to point out another mistake in this approach is that your name array has 9 objects where as icon arrayhas 8.

Comment: I want to display 101 items in recycler view using another arrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the adapter class in `onBindViewHolder` use an if condition

```
    if(arrayList.get(position).getNumber()==101)
{
      // show the required name 
}
```

Comment: @SrilekhaReddy Kindly mark it as the right answer.